# How to parsing trees in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, tree

I need help with this developing this algorithm that I'm working on. I have an input of a tree in the following format:

```
Root -> AB CD
AB -> ABC CBA
CD -> CDE FGH
```

What the algorithm is supposed to is read the parenthetical format in and give the following output:

```
                    Root
                     |
                ____________
              AB           CD
              |             |  
       __________         ___________
      ABC      CBA        CDE      FGH
```

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far? Have you encountered any specific difficulties? As it stands, the question is quite broad, so it would be great if you could help us help you by narrowing down the problem you're facing.

Comment: Have a look to the module `anytree` ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can start from the `networkx` module

1. install the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/):`pip install networkx`
2. install the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/): `pip install matplotlib`
3. program

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # define DiGraph
    tree = nx.DiGraph()

    # add node
    tree.add_node("root")
    tree.add_node("AB")
    tree.add_node("CD")
    tree.add_node("ABC")
    tree.add_node("CBA")
    tree.add_node("CDE")
    tree.add_node("FGH")

    # add connection edge
    tree.add_edge("root","AB")
    tree.add_edge("root","CD")
    tree.add_edge("AB","ABC")
    tree.add_edge("AB","CBA")
    tree.add_edge("CD","CDE")
    tree.add_edge("CD","FGH")

    # output the tree
    nx.draw(tree,with_labels = True)
    plt.show()
```

[image: tree]